# The program compiles with no errors but will not execute.. what is wrong?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class popGrowth
{

    public static void main (String args[])
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double rate = keyboard.nextDouble();
            while (rate != 0.0){ //stops it at zero


            double initialPop = 236; //in millions
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)// i establishes the year
                {
                    int year = i + 2010;// starts the year at 2010
                    double population = initialPop * Math.pow(1+rate/(double)(12*100), (12*i)); //finds population
                    System.out.println("Year: /tPopulation in millions"); 
                    System.out.println(year + "/t " + population); //prints year

            }


            double timeToDouble = 72/rate; //rule of 72
            System.out.println("Time to double " + timeToDouble);
            System.out.print("Please input new rate "); 
            rate = keyboard.nextDouble(); //input for zero

        } 

    }
   }
```

This is my exact code and i do not know why it will not run if it compiles with no errors.

Comment: perhaps its waiting for you to enter a value

Comment: @Reimeus I second that ^

Comment: The output window won't come up to let me enter a value. It is trying to execute but it won't.

Comment: I am able to run the same code.

Comment: Does it work properly? @Rehman

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean by "Does it work properly?". But at least i am getting output. But as per your comment you are not able to execute itself i guess